# gallery image loading problem using galleryView jquery plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

programmers. i need help

I tried to implement jquery galleryview plugin for my image gallery( [this is my image gallery](http://testyourproject.com/integra/client/shareArtMags/testImgLoad.php) ).
The problem i face is it gets some what properly loaded in firefox but, in chrome and safari the condition of the gallery is worse. Gallery doesn't load on first instant (or) on page refresh. On first load of the gallery in chrome and safari i get blank screen and without refreshing the gallery if i visit some url and click browser back button the gallery gets displayed.

Where am i going wrong? How can i get smooth loading of the gallery on other browsers using this galleryview plugin?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you fixed your problem? If so, please share how since I'm experiencing the same problem but don't have the network error Sbml mentions below.

Answer (score 0):

first when the gallery is Loading I get 2 errors:

- "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
  http://testyourproject.com/integra/lib/js/jquery/ui/effects.slide.js"
- "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
  http://testyourproject.com/integra/lib/js/jquery/ui/effects.core.js"

Correct the path to this files.

In the script firebug tells me that:

- dynamicallyResizedContainer is not
  defined resizeTimer =
  setTimeout(dynamicallyResizedContainer,
  100);

  script.js line 140